# running openalpr on docker but volume is not working

Tags: docker, docker-volume, docker-for-windows

I have a docker image named "openalpr/openalpr" and this runs a service against my local file (on host) called `h786poj.jpg`.

I need to use the volume command to let docker see my local file (`$(pwd):/data:ro`) and use directory `/data` (on docker) for that.
I use this command, but I get the error

> docker: invalid reference format

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/data:ro openalpr/openalpr -c eu h786poj.jpg
```

btw: I am running Linux containers on a Windows system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`($pwd)` is bash syntax, but you need to use the appropriate syntax for the shell you're using. Assuming you're using PowerShell (since you mentioned you're using Windows), the current working directory would be `${PWD}`:

```
docker run -it --rm -v ${PWD}:/data:ro openalpr/openalpr -c eu h786poj.jpg
```